# Seria possivel enviar mensagens pré programadas via aplicativos de mensagens?

Tags: java, android

Estou fazendo um aplicativo em AndroidStudio/Java que necessita enviar mensagens constantamente, consiste em um programa de avaliação de qualidade de comercio, que quando for avaliado como ruim será enviado um sms para um numero especifico, porem enviando sms normalmente eu poderia gastar bastante com pacote de sms ...
eu conseguiria vincular minha aplicação com algum aplicativo de mensagens para enviar esses "Avisos" via wifi?
exemplo: Whatsapp ou Hangouts ..

Comment: O whatsapp não tem uma API oficial publica para tal. Você só pode mandar mensagens via Intent para contatos presentes no mesmo telefone que a sua aplicação estiver rodando.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no Slack, parece que ele pode enviar mensagens para o time até quando alguém faz commits no projeto do time no GitHub, então talvez tenha como se conectar a ele para o seu app enviar mensagens automáticas através dele. Talvez também seja o caso de [enviar isso como Logs para nuvem](https://engenharia.elo7.com.br/gestao-de-logs/), ou mesmo o caso de você criar um app que recebe as mensagens. Também deve dá pra enviar as mensagens por e-mail, e fazer o app pegá-las do e-mail pra exibir no cel.